# IPad and scrollTo fails

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad

yes, there are similar questions, where scrollTo doesn't work on Ipad, but I didn't yet find the solution, that works for that little snippet down there. So allow me to ask it again.

```
<body>...pages...more pages...even more pages...
    <span onclick="var top = $('body').offset().top; $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1000);">Scroll to top</span>
<body>
```

This works perfectly for Desktop, but not for Ipad.

BTW: I'm using that code snippet on a bigger page, so if this code works for you (on a minimal page), that would be helpful to know, too.

For Ipad, it waits some time, then jumps directly to the top, instead of scrolling smoothly to the top. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** We have a fixed element on our page, so the currently available solutions won't work.

Thanks,
Bernhard

Comment: http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/ Might want to take a look at this library, apprantly this makes animations alot smoother on mobile devices. I have never used it so i cannot guarantee it will work.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is a fixed element on our page, so the available solutions won't work.